# Is there a way to create asynchronous code in "Vanilla" PHP?

Tags: php, api, asynchronous, zendesk

We have a backend with lots of PHP scripts. In the future we'll probably move to NodeJs so that will take care if itself but I'd love to find a way to make our scripts asynchronous so that it's not blocking.

We use our scripts to handle requests from 3rd-party services (Stripe, Zendesk, etc.) and some of our functions are taking a lot of time and create timeout errors because our PHP code is synchronous.

We're not planning on using something like Laravel (which from what I understand have this baked-in) so it would be great if there was a way to create/handle workers or something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: how are you triggering the script? maybe just let another script handle that, and separate the user flow

Comment: each script is an endpoint on its own so for example we would have `www.example.com/my-script.php` that would receive a POST request with a JSON object as payload and `.../my-other-script.php` would also receive a POST request with another JSON as payload, etc. this multiplied by 50+ scripts and you basically have our backend.
Yeah a handler that sits on top of those would be great. Would you know of any example of how to implement that in plain PHP ?

Comment: I see how we could have a more structured backend with routes such as `$router->get('/some/route', function($request) {....` etc. 
The thing I wonder is how do I implement it in a way that the handling of request is non-blocking so that my 3rd-parties for example Zendesk - are happy with the response they get (they need to get a good old `200` in 4/5 s max.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php with rabbitmq  for amqp protocols so you can dispatch some information on queue and it will be processed outside the code (something like asincornus code ) .  [Here is a link to documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I actually checked out already RabbitMQ. It looks like a great solution if we were to rebuild everything from the ground up. It also looks rather complex though efficient.
Would be great to be able to create workers / queues in Vanilla PHP ❤️